# how to set the left margin for all formulas in the text?

Tags: equations, lists, indentation

My text includes description of a formula and its equation right after that. But each time that I add a new item (description) the corresponding formulas have different indent. How can I change it such that when looking at the whole page, I see all the formulas having the same indent.
Here is the code:

```
\item a
    \begin{align}
    &\sum_{k=1}^{K} ... \label{bal2}&\\
    &\sum_{k=4}^{5}...  \label{bal3}&        \label{bal3}\end{align} 
\item b
    \begin{align}
    &\sum_{j=1}^{J}... \label{bal4}&        \end{align}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly how you want them aligned. Your given example shows them aligned on the left. The `align` environment centers the equations. If you want them aligned on the left when the width of the equations changes then use `flalign`.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: the default is to have equations centered. use can use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` to have all equations start a given distance from the left margin. this distance can be modified using e.g. `\setlength{\mathindent}{2cm}`

Comment: To build on the comments of @PeterGrill and @prettygully, you may also want to change the equation environment from `align` to `gather` since you're not instructing `amsmath` to align vertically the equations on any internal point (say, an equal sign). Making this change will let you get rid of the distracting `&` alignment points.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment of *prettygully*: The default is to have equations centered. use can use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` to have all equations start a given distance from the left margin. this distance can be modified using e.g. `\setlength{\mathindent}{2cm}`