# Uncentered split equations

Tags: equations

I want my equations to start on the left with two tabs.  I use `\qquad\qquad` for this.  When I split an equation with `\begin{equation*}` and `\begin{split}`, TeX centers the equation.  Any advice on how to get the `split` equations to start on the left with two tabs?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean that you use inline math (`$\qquad\qquad ... $`) also for displayed equations, i.e. equations placed on a line of their own? That is not the intended usage, use either `\[ ... \]` or the `equation*` environment (from `amsmath`) for unnumbered equations. For your question, see [how to set the left margin for all formulas in the text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54548) or [how to justify left all numbered equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71146)

Comment: AFAIK, flalgin is the only off-center math environment.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't manually indent equation with `\quad\quad`; use the `fleqn` option to `amsmath` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{2em} % two quads

\begin{document}

Here is an normal equation with some text above it that 
should wrap over a couple of lines
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation*}
and here is a derivation of the above formula using
double integrals, where $C_{r}$ is the full circle
of radius~$r$ centered at the origin and the substitution
uses polar coordinates
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\iint\limits_{C_{r}}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\,dx\,dy
&=\iint\limits_{[0,r]\times[0,2\pi]} e^{-\rho^{2}}\rho\,d\rho\,d\varphi \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\biggl(
    \int_{0}^r \rho e^{-\rho^{2}}\,d\rho
  \biggr)\,d\varphi \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-e^{-r^{2}}}{2} \,d\varphi \\
&=\pi(1-e^{-r^{2}})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
The conclusion is now easy, isn't it?

\end{document}
```

[image]